# Is there any alternative for `marquee` tag in `objective c`

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to move a text of `label` from left to right or vice versa. Means I am finding alternative to `marquee` tag here.  Is there any solutions for this.

[image]

**Code:**

```
-(UIView*)otherView:(UIView *)oview
{  // backgroundImgLogin
    UIImageView *backgroundImgLogin=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, oview.frame.size.width, oview.frame.size.height)];
    backgroundImgLogin.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"green-Home1.jpg"];

    [oview addSubview:backgroundImgLogin];

    //welcome Label
    UILabel *welcomeLabel=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15,45+45+18, 1, 35)];
    [welcomeLabel setText:@"Please enter your login ID and password to continue"];
    [welcomeLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [welcomeLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:20]];
    [welcomeLabel sizeToFit];

    [oview addSubview:welcomeLabel];
    return oview;
}
```

Comment: try this one https://github.com/cbpowell/MarqueeLabel

Comment: What do you mean by 'marque' tag?

Comment: use this one https://github.com/wangzz/WZMarqueeView

Comment: Or better yet, just split your text over two lines - scrolling text would look pretty tacky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the solution is not too complicated because you have to consider that a scrolling is a translation on the x-axis by an arbitrary value. 
It means that step by step, maybe with an UIView animation, you have to add (scroll to the right side of the graphic context) an arbitrary value to the current x value of your label and subtract it if you want to move on the left.

If you want you can download the complete source code of an objective-c marquee implementation here

https://github.com/alchimya/iOS-Marquee

I paste here an obj-c method that (I hope!) can help you.

-(void)scrollContentView:(UIView*)content toDirection:(L3SDKMarqueeDirection)direction withSpeed:(float)speed{

```
CGRect newFrame;
CGRect resetFrame;

//defines the amount of the translation (scrolling) to the x axis
int xProgression=15;


float newX=0;
float resetX=0;

switch (direction) {
    case L3SDKMarqueeDirectionLeft:
        //if the scrolling happens to the left, to define a new translate frame
        //we have to subtract the translation amount (xProgression) from the current x position
        newX=content.frame.origin.x-xProgression;
        //when the scroll will be completed (out of the left side) we have to restart
        //the scrolling from the right side
        resetX=self.frame.size.width;
        break;
    case L3SDKMarqueeDirectionRight:
        //if the scrolling happens to the right, to define a new translate frame
        //we have to add the translation amount (xProgression) from the current x position
        newX=content.frame.origin.x+xProgression;
        //when the scroll will be completed (out of the right side) we have to restart
        //the scrolling from the left side
        resetX=self.frame.origin.x-content.frame.size.width;
        break;
    default:
        break;
}

//defines the scrolling frame
newFrame=CGRectMake(
                    newX,
                    content.frame.origin.y,
                    content.frame.size.width,
                    content.frame.size.height
                    );
//this frame will be applied to the content view to restart the scolling
//on the opposite side
resetFrame=CGRectMake(
                      resetX,
                      content.frame.origin.y,
                      content.frame.size.width,
                      content.frame.size.height
                      );

//defines an animation
[UIView animateWithDuration:speed
                      delay:0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                 animations:^{
                     content.frame =newFrame;
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     BOOL isResetFrame=NO;

                      //checks if the scrolling is completed on the right/left side
                     // and restart the scrolling on the opposite side
                     switch (direction) {
                         case L3SDKMarqueeDirectionRight:

                             if (content.frame.origin.x >=self.frame.size.width) {
                                 isResetFrame=YES;
                             }
                             break;
                         case L3SDKMarqueeDirectionLeft:
                             if ((content.frame.origin.x+content.frame.size.width)<=-self.frame.origin.x) {
                                 isResetFrame=YES;
                             }
                             break;
                         default:
                             break;
                     }

                     if (isResetFrame) {
                         content.frame = resetFrame;
                     }
                     //recursive call
                     [self scrollContentView:content toDirection:direction withSpeed:speed];
                 }];
```

}